# .htaccess recirect domain or sub domain to a variable depending on a database

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am attempting to redirect a domain/sub domain to a variable for example:

```
sub.domain.com --------> domain.com/site/site=sub
domain2.com -----------> domain.com/site/site=domain2
```

this will have to depend on a database value.

Not sure if this is possible using php or .htaccess

Thanks

Siriuo

Comment: What is dependent on database value here?

Comment: So if I have a table called sites within a database and a a field called site-domain then the domain may be sub.domain.com or domain2.com then if possible redirect to a specific folder/page. I hope this makes sense I am trying to word it in a simple way and content would be different depending on a value.

Comment: But rewrite rule cannot query any database.

Comment: Yeah thought it wouldn't be able to. I think I have worked it out so the database wouldn't matter I guess what I am looking to do now is redirect the domains and as the above.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN do this with PHP, but it's a bit overkill if this is something that happens on every request.  If this is something for load balancing, there are better solutions built into SAPIs like `nginx`.

Otherwise, I would actually recommend writing a very simple Node.js application which works like a proxy in front of your application.  The proxy application should query an in-memory database like Redis or even a MySQL MEMORY type database.  You don't want to be waiting on disk reads for redirects.  This would allow your main application (PHP App) to write whatever values are needed to determine the sub-domain routing to the in-memory database, and the simple Node.js would query the database and either supply a `301`/`302` or actually perform in internal pipe if needed.

```
[SAPI (Nginx, Apache, etc)] --- [Node.js Proxy]  --- (if x) --- [PHP domain.com]
                                    |            `-- (if y) --- [301 to PHP sud.domain.com]
                                    | Query DB                           |
                                    |                  Write DB          |
                                [Redis DB]-------------------------------
```